# How to use COUNTIF on date range - only counting duplicates once

Tags: excel-formula, formula, countif, formulas, excel-2016

Currently. I have it set up when someone enters information in column E (**Action Taken**) then the whole row will turn yellow so it is easily seen that that item is being dealt with.

Another conditional format that I have set up is that once 5 working days pass on the date entered into column F (**Date Actioned**) then the row will turn red alerting the user to chase up the issue again.

Every week the user will contact more suppliers on the list regarding the listed product, and fill in their action taken and date actioned.

What I am looking to do is to add up all the suppliers contacted in one week (i.e. week 1 , `05.02.18` to `09.02.18`) Which I know can be done by using the formula;

```
=COUNTIFS(F4:F18,">=5/2/18",F4:F18,"<=9/2/2018")
```

**HOWEVER** I only want to count each company **once**! So even though between the date `05.02.18` to `09.02.18`, **8** actions were carried out, they only contacted **4** suppliers.

Is this possible? (FYI the screenshots attached are just a quick mock-up of the real document which contains thousands of products and more in-depth information).

[image: Table]

[image: Red_Conditional_Formatting]

[image: Yellow_Conditional_Formatting]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! I knew there would be a simple solution I was just overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding a couple of working columns, the following is a possible solution:

#### Step 1

Set up two cells to contain the min and max dates for your range that you used in your formula `=COUNTIFS(F4:F18,">=5/2/18",F4:F18,"<=9/2/2018")`.  This will allow you to up date things without having to recopy the formula each time.  I used cells E1 and G1 for min and max date respectively.

#### Step 2

In a new column generate a list of supplier IDs that match your criteria.  I arbitrarily chose column H.  I placed the following formula in H4 and copied down:

```
=IF(AND(F4>=$E$1,F4<=$G$1),A4,"")
```

#### Step 3

In a new column generate a list of the count of the first time a supplier ID occurs from column H and do not count blank spaces.  I arbitrarily chose column I.  I placed the following formula in I4 and copied down:

```
=--(AND(COUNTIF($H$4:H4,H4)=1,H4<>""))
```

#### Step 4

Take the sum of the results from step 3.  I arbitrarily chose to place the following formula in I19:

```
=SUM(I4:I18)
```

[image: POC]

Answer (score 0):

The "cop out" route, if you were only doing the calculation for 1 week would be to have a Pivot Table, with the Company as the Rows and the Date as the Columns.  Then filter your columns, and you get a row per Company that week.

The Full route means looking into Array Formulae - you type one of these like normal, but instead of pressing [Enter], you press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter], and the equation will show in curly braces.  (This is why they are sometimes called "CSE Formula" for "Control, Shift, Enter")

**~Warning - This is a long walk through how I calculated the final formula.  Hopefully it will make sense though!~**

An array formula lets you iterate through every row in a range, calculate them seperately, and then add them all together at the end.  This gives us the outside term - everything goes inside a `=SUM(..)`.  Press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter], and this will display as `{=SUM(..)}`

Now, what calculation do we want to be doing per row?  Well, for every row where column F is within date, you want 1 **per** company within date.  Well, another was to say "per" is "divided by" (hence the "Percentage" symbol being "0 / 0" or "%", and the lesser knows "Permille" symbol being "0 / 00" or "‰")

*For the sake of reproducibility, I am going to assume that your Count is being done in Cell J2, and you have the Start/End of week dates in Cells H2 and I2*

The formula for Row 4 would start out as `=IF(AND(F4>=$H2,F4<=$I2), 1/???, 0)`, where `???` is how many times the Company on row 4 appears.  Unfortunately, the `AND` function does not work with Array Formula.  *Fortunately* there is an easy workaround - since boolean True/False can be treated as binary 1/0, the AND operator is the same as multiplication.  Converting from boolean to binary is fastest by double-negation, so `AND(F4>=H2,F4<=I2)` can be rewritten as `--(F4>=H2)*--(F4<=I2)`, which will work fine with array formula, giving us `=IF(--(F4>=H2)*--(F4<=I2), 1/???, 0)`

Now, before we work out what `???` should be, I'm going to skip down to row 18.  There is method to this madness, I promise!  Following the rules laid out above, the formula for row 18 is `=IF(--(F18>=H2)*--(F18<=I2), 1/???, 0)` - fairly simple?  Now, if we want to run this for all rows from 4 to 18, *we just need to join the ranges*.  So, you would get `=IF(--(F4:F18>=H2)*--(F4:F18<=I2), 1/???, 0)`  Turning this into an Array Formula would get you an array of "1/???"s and "0"s, so add it together with `SUM` to get a single 'flat' number:  `=SUM(IF(--(F4:F18>=H2)*--(F4:F18<=I2), 1/???, 0))`

Remember that "method" I mentioned earlier?  Well, if we were looking for a straight Count of actions taken, ignoring the Unique Companies constraint, we could make `???` = 1, to get `=SUM(IF(--(F4:F18>=$H2)*--(F4:F18<=$I2), 1, 0))` and hit [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] - which would give the same result as `=COUNTIF(F4:F18, ">="&H2, F4:F18, "<="&I2)` - and changing the `1` to `D4:D18` would be a `SUMIF` on Products.  (Incidentally, you can remove the IF statement from the CountIf, since the Condition returns 1 or 0 already)

So, last step!  What is `???`  Well, it's a Count of rows where Date Actioned is within our date bounds, and Company is the same as the current row.  So, for Row 4 you have `COUNTIFS(B4:B18, B4, F4:F18, ">="&H2, F4:F18, "<="&I2)`, and for Row 18 you get `COUNTIFS(B4:B18, B18, F4:F18, ">="&H2, F4:F18, "<="&I2)`, making the final `???` become `COUNTIFS(B4:B18, B4:B18, F4:F18, ">="&H2, F4:F18, "<="&I2)`  (The trick here is that the **Range** arguments are treated as all the cells at once, but the **Condition** arguments are treated as an array of each cell one-at-a-time)

Now, some people might argue that you need to put your `1/COUNTIFS(B4:B18, B4:B18, F4:F18, ">="&H2, F4:F18, "<="&I2)` inside an `IFERROR` to be safe - however, this is in the `TRUE` part of an `IF` statement referrring to the same row, so we know that if the `COUNTIF` is being evaluated then there will *always* be at least 1 row that matches.

So, if we stick it all together, and add a load of `$` symbols to lock the rows/columns in place (so that you can drag down column J to calculate for different weeks/dates in columns H and I) you get the (slightly unwieldy) formula as follows:

```
=SUM(IF(--($F$4:$F$18>=$H2)*--($F$4:$F$18<=$I2), 1/COUNTIFS($B$4:$B$18, $B$4:$B$18, $F$4:$F$18, ">=" & $H2, $F$4:$F$18, "<=" & $I2), 0))
```

And, one last time - *Don't forget to press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]*

(The 2 Date cells, $H2 and $I2 are the only terms I have left 'unlocked', and even then only on the Row)